# How to get the tree structure for the dependencies in the Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-package-manager

**Is there any way to get the tree structure of the dependencies in Xcode?**

Example - Suppose I have integrated a library A (through SPM) and it has the dependency library A1, A2 and A3. So in my project if I see under Packaged Dependencies, there are 4 libraries A, A1, A2 and A3.

Now I got some problem in library A3 and want to know by which dependency the A3 library come in my project. By going through the `Package.Resolved` for every dependency is difficult because I have n number of dependencies. So is there any way to get the dependency tree in Xcode.

Comment: Good discussion at https://forums.swift.org/t/tracing-dependencies-and-generating-dependency-graphs/51099. For a solution see https://swiftpackageindex.com/simonbs/dependency-graph